# What are the connotations of the word “pedantry”?

Tags: meaning, definition, connotations

This is a request of help for the connotations of a word

If native speakers hear the word, ***pedantry***, does it assume an air of showy, academically pompous, impudent impression to them?

Would this word or these words, *pedantry* or *pedant*, mean a person who is excessively fussy on academic minutia and thus a bit irritable to us?

Comment: What do you mean by "does it (the word) assume an air"? Are you asking whether the listener would regard the person who used that word as pompous, or if the word has that meaning?  Also, you should use the word in a sentence.  Context is hardly irrelevant when asking about "airs".  *We should seek to avoid pedantry* is far different from *Your work offers no new insights and is nothing but pedantry*

Comment: Sorry for the lack of my good presentation. As a matter of fact, >" Are you asking whether the listener would regard the person who used that word as pompous, or if the word has that meaning?" Yes I am and it does.Anyway, thanks.

Comment: One who uses the word **pedantry** is not a pedant merely for doing so.

Comment: What would that possibly mean by your saying so? Would you kindly break it down a little bit? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question about "by your saying so".  Are you referring to the phrase  "merely for doing so" in my comment above?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Would this word or these words, pedantry or pedant, mean, a person who is excessively minute on academic minutia and thus a bit irritable to us?

Comment: You said earlier that you're not interested in the meaning of the word, but how a person would be received *when using the word*. Now you're asking for the meaning of the word.  How people react to a pedant is not part of the definition of *pedantry*.

Comment: I didn't say I was not interested in the meaning of the word. But on the contrary. Though I am sorry to say, since asking somewhereelse looks more promising, I would like to delete this. Anywa, thank you for your assistance so far.

Comment: Thank you for editing Mari-Lou-A. The smartest woman I have never met before^^.

Comment: Look at the mistakes I've corrected. This should help you with the TOEFL writing...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I appreciate that very much. You are one of the the smartest and kindest people here in the ELL and ELU too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... and thus a bit irritable to us?

No, there is nothing about the definition of **pedant** or **pedantry** that relates to people's reactions to the behavior, just as there is nothing about the definition of **murder** that relates to the way people react to it.

And *words* do not "assume airs".  Speakers assume airs.

The basic meanings of those words can be found in good dictionaries.